# How to edit a property of GameViewController from GameScene

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit

I wish to make a view appear in front of the scene to simulate a text box narration. Due to the limitations of SklabelNode, I preferred using UILabel for its animation capabilities and text wrap function.

Code from gameScene.swift

```
var viewController = GameViewController()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        viewController.printStuff()

        viewController.uiLabelContainer.isHidden = false

    }
```

Code from GameViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Load 'GameScene.sks' as a GKScene. This provides gameplay related content
        // including entities and graphs.
        if let scene = GKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {

            // Get the SKScene from the loaded GKScene
            if let sceneNode = scene.rootNode as! GameScene? {

                // Copy gameplay related content over to the scene
                sceneNode.entities = scene.entities
                sceneNode.graphs = scene.graphs

                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                sceneNode.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                sceneNode.viewController = self
                // Present the scene
                if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
                    view.presentScene(sceneNode)
                    view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

                    view.showsFPS = true
                    view.showsNodeCount = true
                }
            }
        }
        uiLabelContainer.isHidden = true

    }

func printStuff()  {
        print("this works, calling from gameviewcontroller")
    }
```

Calling the function from gameviewcontroller works and even printing off of what's on UILabel (accessing data from variables or objects from another class). However changing the properties of one of the objects (uiLabelContainer) from gameViewController to .isHidden = false does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was happened because you re-create the `GameViewController` inside your scene with the line:

```
var viewController = GameViewController()
```

instead of get the already existent `GameViewController`.

There are many ways to solve your issue.
So, for example using the "*hello world*" **Sprite-kit** template if you have your `GameViewController` as the initial viewController of your game you can do:

### GameViewController:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    var uiLabelContainer:UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        uiLabelContainer = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0,y: 0,width: 250,height: 50))
        uiLabelContainer.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
        uiLabelContainer.textColor = .white
        uiLabelContainer.text = "This is a Label"
        self.view.addSubview(uiLabelContainer)
        uiLabelContainer.isHidden = true
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }
            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
    }
    func printStuff() {
        print("printStuff")
    }
}
```

### GameScene:

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene {
    private var label : SKLabelNode?
    var viewController : GameViewController!
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.label = self.childNode(withName: "//helloLabel") as? SKLabelNode
        if let label = self.label {
            label.alpha = 0.0
            label.run(SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 2.0))
        }
        self.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2),completion:{[unowned self] in
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            if let vc = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController {
                self.viewController = vc as! GameViewController
                self.viewController.uiLabelContainer.isHidden = false
            }
        })
        self.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 5),completion:{[unowned self] in
            let scene2 = GameScene2()
            scene2.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            self.view?.presentScene(scene2)
        })
    }
    deinit {
        print("\n THE SCENE \((type(of: self))) WAS REMOVED FROM MEMORY (DEINIT) \n")
    }
}
```

### GameScene2:

(created only for test, to see the correct `GameScene` deallocation)

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene2: SKScene {
    private var label : SKLabelNode?
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        print("gameScene2")
    }
}
```

**Output**:[image]

Comment: Thanks man! This line of code here: 

let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            if let vc = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController {
                self.viewController = vc as! GameViewController
                self.viewController.uiLabelContainer.isHidden = false
            } 

was the key!!!

Comment: You're a lifesaver! :)

Comment: I scoured the internet for this.  This is definitely the key here.

 let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate ;


            if let vc = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController {
                self.viewController = vc as! GameViewController             
            }